# Visual C# - Check Exception On Running

Tags: c#, visual-studio

some of you have read and answered my questions on this matter before. Well, I had a busy school semester and so I'm just coming back to this problem now.
I'm strongly considering rewriting the application I have spoken about before, possibly using something like Java.
However, I would like to possibly try to catch whatever unhandled exception is being thrown at the beginning of my program. However, my limited knowledge of C# makes me unsure how to do this. So here is the problem, as I've stated before:
I programmed this application using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. The application was intended for Windows XP SP2, however.
When I attempt to run the application on the XP machine, it delivers the ol' Send Error Report window. The program crashes before it is even able to run. So I ran the only debugger available on the machine (which was part of Visual C++) and it mentioned something about an unhandled exception.

So I would like to use a try catch statement to figure out what possible unhandled exception might be being thrown (meaning I'd encase the main method in a try-catch and if an exception is thrown, print to the command line a message)

My issue is...where in my code do I put this?

My code is quite long, so I couldn't post it here. I've linked to it here:
http://www.raw-d.com/code.cs

Comment: You should probably use the "Debug" feature of VS2010 to do this.  I can promise you it will be much easier than just seeing what the error is.  At the top of your VS screen you can see the little green arrow.  Next to it is a box that says "Debug" or "Release".  Set it to "Debug."  Then spread break points starting with one in your Main() function at the very beginning and step through instruction by instruction until the code pops up an Exception.

Comment: See this question for information on how to setup a `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler`. And then use the handler to log all the information about the exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344100/c-app-runs-in-windows-7-but-not-in-windows-xp

Comment: Chances are that you are compiling with a .NET runtime that is not installed on the target machine.

Comment: @Cpfohl The problem with this is that I am not having the issue on my own machine, I'm having it only on the Windows XP SP2 machine. In order to install Visual Studio 2010 on the machine, I'd need to upgrade it to SP3, which I cannot do due to compatibility issues on the machine (and lack of internet connectivity).

Comment: @Oded I installed all of the framework versions that could have been possible (3.5, 4, etc.) and it still would not run.

Comment: @unholysampler So I (think I) coded the UnhandledExceptionEventHandler and still it refuses to tell me of any such errors, it simply crashes. Arrghh debugging.

Comment: I looked at your code and the `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` is there, but it is in `FileSort_Load()`. You want to add the handler as early as possible, preferably in `Main()`. Without looking at your other code, I can't know what happens before `FileSort_Load()` or if it even gets called.

Comment: Have you debugged the application? What exactly was the error message?

Comment: I don't recall now as I won't be in the office again until after the holidays, but I can test it on my XP computer...on which I do not have the debugger.

Comment: However what I can do is possibly install VS 2008 on my virtual machine that has Windows XP on it (on which I'm getting the same error) and try to debug it using that.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can put your try catch exception in the Main()

2) you can handle AppDomain.UnhandledExpception event

3) Some features of .Net 4 are not available on Xp maybe you are making use of those.

4) Don't switch to java

Comment: Why do you want to switch to Java anyway?