# How to create a program (.exe file) for WinXP on VC# 2013 Express on Win 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, package, porting

(Background: Just started using VC# and .NET)

Hi, I have a simple project which I started developing on Win7 (Pro), using VC# Express edition. It works well when I send it to the client who wanted to use it on Win7 Pro. I used to use "Build -> Publish" to generate the setup.exe and the relevant files. (Both development and client machines are very similar, Win7 Pro, 64-bit etc)

However, now the requirement changed and the client wants to use it on a different machine which is on WinXP Pro (32-bit) and it doesn't have an internet connection (it cannot be ever put on internet).

1. I used "Any CPU" option, made sure that the .Net version matches (Both have ver 4.0 Client profile". Since this PC will not have internet connection, I unchecked "Create setup program to install prerequisite components".
2. The program installs on the XP machine, but when it tries to launch it displays an error dialog "encounted a problem, need to close, send an error report to MS".I am not before the XP machine,so I don't know the "details" part of it.
3. I installed VC# 2010 express on the client machine and tried to open the solution file, but I get an error saying that the solution file cannot be opened because it was created with a newer version of VC#.
4. Ideally I would need to generate an installation file, which will uninstall the previous version and use a newer version (we need to go back and forth on any changes). But that is not a requirement as of now.

Any idea how should I go about getting this program installed on a WinXP machine? I don't have access to an XP license to test it in a virtual machine.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd setup a Windows XP VM and test to see what the actual error code/message is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# app runs in Windows 7, but not in Windows XP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344100/c-sharp-app-runs-in-windows-7-but-not-in-windows-xp)